# yum and rpm nothing happens

Tags: centos, yum, centos6, rpm

I am experiencing an odd problem in CentOS 6.

when I try to use yum or rpm nothing happens.

For example if I type

```
yum update
```

it simply returns to the command prompt.

I have checked that yum and rpm exists in /usr/bin and it is present and the permissions are correct. I have even copied the yum binary file from another server and still it does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas on what to try to resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you run `rpm -qa` and `yum clean all; yum info yum`?

Comment: Nothing at all. Its like the command does not exist...but it does. Very odd. We have had to rebuild the server to resolve the issue.

Comment: Odd indeed. Sounds like there was a library package that did not get installed or installed properly.

Comment: You probably should post the system rebuild as the answer to this question and then accept your own answer.

Comment: Not really a fix but when limited on time this is what we had to do.

Comment: I know this is old but I had the same issue. For me my memory usage was too high, I didn't have any free memory. So for others that stumble across this problem, mem usage could be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final solution was to completely re-install the operating system. Not an ideal fix but we could not see another way around it.

edit: Turns out my colleague installed dante-server on the server. The rpm from epel is broken and causes major issues on CentOS servers currently. To resolve the issue stop dante-server from running.